# Converting a List type<Integer> to String[] Array using method reference

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert a List of type Integer to an Array of Strings. I want to do it using the method reference passed to toArray() as below, which must work somehow since my CS professor showed this to us in class.

```
     List<Integer> strawberry = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
             .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

     String[] plum = strawberry.toArray(String[]::new);
```

However I got the following error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.lang.String
    at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

How can this be fixed?

I know there are easier ways of doing this, but I want to learn how to use this method correctly. Thanks.

Comment: You have a list of integers. You need to convert them to strings before you can store them in a string array. The problem is not with the method, it's trying to use it with the wrong data type.

Comment: How you are getting the exception. I believe the code you posted will not compile even. Which version of java you are using?

Comment: @AmitBera this can be compiled with Java 11, which added the method [`toArray​(IntFunction<T[]>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)) to collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first map to a string stream:

```
String[] plum = strawberry.stream()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

But you can do both in one step:

```
String[] plum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
         .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
         .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

One you need both `stream` and `valueOf` from `String:

```
List<Integer> strawberry = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

String[] plum = strawberry.stream().map(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
```